# Image processing in iOS to get an object status

Tags: iphone

I am new to iOS projects. In my current project, I have to process an image which contains LED object. I want to extract the LED object status (on/off) from that image in iOS. Is there any open source library to process the image for my scenario. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is an opencv port for ios.
Check following link
http://www.eosgarden.com/en/opensource/opencv-ios/overview/

Answer (score 0):

You could use OpenCV. But honestly for what you want to do, doing it yourself would be way easier.